# Why all my letters getting printed after just one second?

Tags: javascript

```
let data = document.querySelector(".data");
let arr = ["Hello", "Random", "Word"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(arr[i][k]);
      }, 1000);
}
}
```

What I want is to print H first then after a second E then after a sec L then after a sec L and so on and on . But all My letters are getting printed individually like

"H"

"e"

"l"

"l"

.

.

.

all together after just one second and not one by one by one.

shouldn't the second for loop wait one second and then print them?

Comment: You're invoking 15 one second timeouts, but you're invoking them all at once.

Comment: Because all the timeouts get started at virtually the same time and they all then get  triggered at the same time.

Comment: Your loop ends in under 10ms. So you are adding 1s timeout almost instantaneously. Use `1000 * (i+k)` instead

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I just realised setTimeout is async. How can I get the desired effect?

Comment: @phuzi  just realised setTimeout is async. How can I get the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the loop for is immediately scheduled so there's microseconds difference between each execution.

In order to have it execute with a certain delay you could use some maths using the indexes in your for-loops:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
      setTimeout(() => { console.log(arr[i][k]);}, 1000 + (1000*i) + (100*k));
    }
}
```

Or alternatively use `async / await` to await the printing of the words:

```js
function printDelayed(letter, delayMS) {
  return new Promise(res => { 
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(letter); res(); }, delayMS)
  })
}


async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
        await printDelayed(arr[i][k], 100)
      }
  }
}

main().then().catch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```js
let arr = ["Hello", "Random", "Word"];

const iv = setInterval(printLetters(arr), 200);

function printLetters(arr,i=0,j=0){
 return function(){
  if (i<arr.length) 
    if (j<arr[i].length) console.log(arr[i][j++]);
    else {j=0;i++;}
  else clearInterval(iv);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's `setTimeout`doesn't wait on the spot, it enlists the supplied function into a queue immediately. This means that you're effectively iterating over all characters, adding them all to a queue at the same time with one second of delay, which then all get printed after one second. To combat this, you can use the solution by Some random IT boy, or wait in the for loop:

```js
function sleepSync(ms) {
    let start = Date.now();
    while(start + ms > Date.now());
}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
      console.log(arr[i][k]);
      sleepSync(1000);
    }
}
```